# How to add a scripting engine to Gecko or Webkit?

Tags: webkit, browser, gecko

I would like to understand what is involved in adding support for a non-Javascript scripting engine to Gecko or Webkit.  I've looked through the documentation, but don't see what interface an engine must implement nor any mechanism for registering an engine.

My goal is to support a tag like this: `<script type="text/scheme" src="web-ui.scheme">`

To be very clear, I am not interested in compiling to Javascript.  I would like to know how to implement and deploy a scripting engine that has no dependencies on Javascript whatsoever.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think Dartium is a good reference for your request of add script engine (Dartium adds Dart engine to Chromium/Blink: `<script type="application/dart">`).

See Dartium: https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/BuildingDartium